# Having trouble centering an image in CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment, centering

I am trying to horizontally center an image within a div. However, I haven't been able to. I've tried setting the vertical-align to middle and the margin to auto, 0 auto, and every variation I can think of. Nothing works. Here is the code for how it is currently set up:

```
img {
border: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.intro img {
border-radius: 50%;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 10px;
}
```

The image is in the intro div. Any advice you can give would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center images on a web page for all screen sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901789/how-to-center-images-on-a-web-page-for-all-screen-sizes)

Comment: Did you mean *vertically* center?

Comment: If you are in fact trying to horizontally center it, you're close. You just need to add a width to the image in order for `margin: 0 auto;` to work.

Comment: I meant horizontally center. I just wasn't finding any solutions that worked in any of the previously created tags. I did find the solution in the link Youka posted, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to center your image both horizontally & vertically, this should do the trick :

```css
 .intro {
    display: table;
    width: 500px; /* works with any width */
    height: 150px; /* works with any height */
    background: #ccc;
}

.imgcontainer {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
   <div class="imgcontainer">
     <img src="http://s.gravatar.com/avatar/bf4cc94221382810233575862875e687?r=x&s=50" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:relative` in parent `.intro` and use the code shown below in `img`, it will work with any `width` and `height`

```
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0
```

## Snippet

```css
.intro {
  border: dashed red; /* demo */
  display:inline-block; /* demo */
  vertical-align:top; /* demo */
  position: relative
}
.intro img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0
}
.intro:first-of-type {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.intro:last-of-type {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" />
</div>
<div class="intro">
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The css style `margin: 0 auto;` should do the horizontal part of the trick.
For the vertical part you also need to take care of the parent.
Look at [How to vertically align an image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` works only in table cells. Try to use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout). The element containing your image should have CSS properties:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: you are wrong, ´vertical-align´ **applies to** *inline-level and table-cell elements. It also applies to `::first-letter` and `::first-line`*. [vertical-align in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Comment: So after all not entirely wrong :) Anyway, won't work the way he did it.